# Error reading a csv file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following is my code snippet I try to run in my jupyter notebook:

```
import os
#print(os.path.expanduser("~"))

import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\sonaw\Data\dump4.csv")
print(data)
```

This is the error message I get when running the code snippet:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-535fb23b20c4> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 data_filename = "dump4.csv"
----> 3 dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/sonaw/Data/dump4.csv")
      4 print(dataset.head())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()`enter code here`

FileNotFoundError: File b'C:/Users/sonaw/Data/dump4.csv' does not exist
```

Why am I seeing this error? What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: The error says "File not found" - are you certain that the file exists?

Comment: Double check the file path you've given, it says does not exist so my bet would be an incorrect file path.

Comment: Thanks all..this problem was solved. Apparently the path was correct but the file was huge and needed to properly name user_cols & put low_memory=False while reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all..this problem was solved. Apparently the path was correct but the file was huge and needed to properly name user_cols & put low_memory=False while reading the file. This allowed me to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

its very common and same error i have come across this morning, the solution for this will be. 
First: look whether you file format is .csv only or not? is not convert the same into csv. 
secondly: while you use windows you have to use the following backslash formate.

:/Users/patel/Desktop/

try doing this will resolve you issue.